# Find a conformal map between two sectors.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics

It is clear that the module of annular regions $v=\{(r,\theta): r_1<r<r_2, a<\theta<b\} $ is $m=\frac{r2}{r1}$. But how can I find a conformal mapping between two sector $A=\left(r_1<r<r_2, \frac{-\pi}{4}< \theta < \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$   and $B=\left(R_1 < r < R_2, \frac{-\pi}{2}< \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ which have different angle ? Thanks..

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the "module" of a region???

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222319/conformal-maps-between-annulus

Comment: Dear David, i must be find a conformal mapping rule for two sectorial regions which have different sector angles. i is very crucial for me.

Comment: @halis That link is for the module of an annulus, it does not apply to an annulus **region**, so your question is ill-founded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use 
$$z\longmapsto a(bz)^\alpha.$$
You can determinate $a,b,\alpha$ using polar coordinates.

EDIT: I understand that the "moduli" (your definition $\ne$ the link definition) of both regions are related as $M = m^2$.

By the geometric interpretation of the product of two complex numbers (argument of product is...), $\alpha = 2$ obviously. We want also
$$|z| = r_i\implies |a||b|^2|z|^2 = |a(bz)^2| = R_i,\qquad i = 1,2.$$
As no rotation required, $a$ and $b$ will be real an positive. This implies
$$ab^2 r_i^2 = R_i,\qquad i = 1,2.$$
$$ab^2 = \frac{R_1}{r_1^2} = \frac{R_2}{r_2^2}.$$

Comment: Dear Martin, can you describe it in more detail please. Because I do not know the complex analysis in detail.

Comment: Thanks, but This is not depend on the sector angle. i think that it must be related with the angle because we have two sector which have two different angle.